# jquery check if URL has a querystring already

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, url

If it is the first time site is loading, then when user selects the location dropdown for hospital, it should pass the hos=somelocation as querystring to the URL. 
http://mysite/events/Pages/default.aspx?hos=Munster

If the URL already has one along with other querystring like
http://mysite/events/Pages/default.aspx?kwd=cancer&hos=Munster

then I need to check for if &hos already is in the window.location.search..and if there is one already, then replace whatever value it has with the one recently selected without appending to it like this:
http://mysite/events/Pages/default.aspx?kwd=cancer&hos=Munster&hos=Carmel -> which is not what I want. I want this to be http://mysite/events/Pages/default.aspx?kwd=cancer&hos=Carmel once user selects Carmel from the location Dropdown. Someone Please Help!!

```
$(".LocationDropDown").change(function(e){
    var querystring=window.location.search;
    var currentURL=$(location).attr('href');
    if(querystring=='') {
        window.location.href= ( $(this).val() == "All Hospitals" ) ? 'http://mysitee/events/Pages/default.aspx':'http://mysite/events/Pages/default.aspx?hos='+$(this).val();
        }
        else            
          {
            window.location.href = ( $(this).val() == "All Hospitals" ) ? 'http://mysitee/events/Pages/default.aspx':currentURL+'&hos'+$(this).val();
   }
});
```

Comment: If a plugin is an option for you - this solution may suffice - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters-with-jquery

Comment: JavaScript could use [a good URI object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7853496/497418)...

Answer (score 0):

Try the [BBQ plugin for jQuery](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/). It's really simple to use and the best plugin if you're going to be using multiple querystring values like your example.

To get the variables, you can use:

```
$.bbq.getState( "kwd" );
$.bbq.getState( "hos" );
```

and to set the state:

```
$.bbq.pushState({ hos: Carmel }); //pushState has an optional 2nd param 
//for whether or not to delete all the params not in the push function or to keep them.
```

and to execute a function on URL change:

```
$(window).bind( "hashchange", function(e) {
    // In jQuery 1.4, use e.getState( "url" );
    var url = $.bbq.getState( "url" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is may be due to the use of currentURL variable in the else part.Use http://mysite/events/Pages/default.aspx?hos='+$(this).val(); instead of currentURL

Answer (score 0):

I hate just linking out to site, but I found this person's solution and it looks quite good for getting and setting url parameters via javascript.

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Sep/07/Get-and-Set-Querystring-Values-in-JavaScript

```
//check if querystring contains hos
if (getUrlEncodedKey('hos', location.search) != '') {
     //set new value
     setUrlEncodedKey('hos', newval);
}

getUrlEncodedKey = function(key, query) {
    if (!query)
        query = window.location.search;    
    var re = new RegExp("[?|&]" + key + "=(.*?)&");
    var matches = re.exec(query + "&");
    if (!matches || matches.length < 2)
        return "";
    return decodeURIComponent(matches[1].replace("+", " "));
}
setUrlEncodedKey = function(key, value, query) {

    query = query || window.location.search;
    var q = query + "&";
    var re = new RegExp("[?|&]" + key + "=.*?&");
    if (!re.test(q))
        q += key + "=" + encodeURI(value);
    else
        q = q.replace(re, "&" + key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "&");
    q = q.trimStart("&").trimEnd("&");
    return q[0]=="?" ? q : q = "?" + q;
}

//There are a couple of helpers in use here. For completeness here they are as well:    
String.prototype.trimEnd = function(c) {
    if (c)        
        return this.replace(new RegExp(c.escapeRegExp() + "*$"), '');
    return this.replace(/\s+$/, '');
}
String.prototype.trimStart = function(c) {
    if (c)
        return this.replace(new RegExp("^" + c.escapeRegExp() + "*"), '');
    return this.replace(/^\s+/, '');
}

String.prototype.escapeRegExp = function() {
    return this.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\/\\]/g, "\\$0");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint of code, not tested though.

```
$(".LocationDropDown").change(function(e){
    var querystring=window.location.search;
    var currentURL=$(location).attr('href');
    if(querystring=='') {
        window.location.href= ( $(this).val() == "All Hospitals" ) ? 'http://mysitee/events/Pages/default.aspx':'http://mysite/events/Pages/default.aspx?hos='+$(this).val();
    }
    else if(str.indexOf("hos=")==-1)
    {
        window.location.href = ( $(this).val() == "All Hospitals" ) ? 'http://mysitee/events/Pages/default.aspx':currentURL+'&hos='+$(this).val();
    }
    else{
        window.location.href= ( $(this).val() == "All Hospitals" ) ? 'http://mysitee/events/Pages/default.aspx': getReplacedValForHospital(currentURL, $(this).val());
    }
});
function getReplacedValForHospital(currentURL, hospitalVal) {
    var tempString = currentURL.substring(currentURL.indexOf("hos="));
    currentURL = currentURL.replace(tempString,"hos="+hospitalVal);
    return currentURL;
}
```